# Solr admin shows number of indexes(numDocs) to be greater than the number of files I processed

Tags: django, solr, indexing, django-haystack

When I process 56 files with Solr it says, 'numDoc:74'. I have no clue as to why more indexes would exists than files processed, but one explanation I came up with is that the indexes of a couple of the processed files are too big, so they are split up into multiple indexes(I use rich content extraction on all processed files) . It was just a thought, so I don't want to take it as true right off the bat. Can anyone give an alternate explanation or confirm this one?

using Django + Haystack + Solr.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you post your `search.py` module?

Comment: you mean the search_indexes.py for haystack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your terminology is unfortunately is all incorrect but the troubleshooting process should be simple enough. Solr comes with admin console. Usually at **http:// [ localhost or domain ]:8983/solr/** . Go there, find your collection in the drop-down (I am assuming Solr 4) and run the default query in the Query screen. That should give you all your documents and you can see what the extras are.

I suspect you may have some issues with your unique ids and/or reindexing. But with the small number of documents you can really just review what you are actually storing in Solr and figure out what is not correct.

Comment: OK thanks! Ill check it out. Whats is specifically wrong with my terminology? I would like to know so I can fix it.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "indexes" in that message. Solr has collections that have documents which consist of fields (and nested documents). There is "index" (and shard and other things) but they are more on technical level discussion.